# Is there a more efficient way to create a macro code with a global function to alter a column?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a column ID with both string and int values. I wanted to insert a dash between the string and int for those ID values. However, I am not sure where to start. Any advice or tip would be greatly appreciated.

I have this in PROC SQL code:

```
PROC SQL;
select 
case when ID CONTAINTS "ABC" THEN CATX("-", SUBSTR(ID,1,3), SUBSTR(ID,3,6)
when ID CONTAINTS "AB" THEN CATX("-", SUBSTR(ID,1,2), SUBSTR(ID,2,7) 
when ID CONTAINTS "ABCS" THEN CATX("-", SUBSTR(ID,1,4), SUBSTR(ID,4,6)
else ID
end as ID,
Name, Age, Gender
from A;
quit;
```

Example from this:

```
|ID       |Name   |Age|Gender|
|123456789|Sam    |30 |M     |
|232456676|Jessica|20 |F     |
|ABC134475|Suzen  |29 |F     |
|AB1235674|Alex   |26 |M     |
|ABCS24563|NON    |15 |F     |
```

To this:

```
|ID        |Name   |Age|Gender|
|123456789 |Sam    |30 |M     |
|232456676 |Jessica|20 |F     |
|ABC-134475|Suzen  |29 |F     |
|AB-1235674|Alex   |26 |M     |
|ABCS-24563|NON    |15 |F     |
```

Comment: How did you envision macro code being involved here?  Is the name of the dataset or the name of the variable changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`compress`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_032/fedsqlref/n01p24mgwawxa2n1hy4gwe5t59xf.htm) function with specific modifiers to extract the character and numeric values from alphanumeric strings, then concatenate with the desired delimiter.

```
data want;
set have;
char = compress(id, '', "D");
num = compress(id, '', "A");

if not missing(char) and not missing(num) then id = catx('-', char, num);
else if not missing(char) and missing(num) then id = char;
else if missing(char) and not missing(num) then id = num;
else id = '';

drop char num;
run;
```

```
+------------+---------+-----+--------+
|     ID     |  Name   | Age | Gender |
+------------+---------+-----+--------+
| 123456789  | Sam     |  30 | M      |
| 232456676  | Jessica |  20 | F      |
| ABC-134475 | Suzen   |  29 | F      |
| AB-1235674 | Alex    |  26 | M      |
| ABCS-24563 | NON     |  15 | F      |
+------------+---------+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SAS function `PRXCHANGE` to perform PERL regular expression substitutions that compute the new ID value.

Example:

```
data have;
length ID $9 Name $20 Age 8 Gender $1;
input ID   Name    Age Gender; datalines;
 123456789 Sam     30  M      
 232456676 Jessica 20  F      
 ABC134475 Suzen   29  F      
 AB1235674 Alex    26  M      
 ABCS24563 NON     15  F      
 ;

 proc sql;
   create table want as
   select prxchange ('s/^([a-z]+)/$1-/i', 1, id) as id length=9
   , name, age, gender
   from have;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a column ID with both char and int values. You have a column ID with char values. Some of them are numbers, some are letters. There is a difference. Also, you don't need a macro code to alter your column.

Using compress function for example should work just fine:

```
data have;
    input ID :$20.;
    datalines;
123456789
232456676
ABC134475
AB1235674
ABCS24563
A2020920
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    number=compress(ID,,"kd");
    letters=compress(ID,,"ka");
    if ID ne number then do;
        ID=cats(letters,'-',number);
    end;
    drop number letters;
run;
```

Mind you, this will only work if your IDs are always like you have shown. If they are completely mixed (for example: A5S8ER31), it would take a bit more work to separate them with dashes. Even worse would be if other symbols get mixed into your IDs.